# unwind segue - detect when animation completes

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, modalviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I love using unwind segues but have came into a problem...

I have a parent controller (call it *Home*) that presents a child modally (call it *Detail*).

The Detail controller has a tableview that's showing a collection of core data entities, and I have a Delete button, when it's tapped I want to delete all those entities, and dismiss the modal, and update the home controller to show that the entities have been deleted.

My first attempt of `self.context.deleteObject(entity)` followed by an unwind segue worked, except in the situation where there are enough entities that the tableview can scroll with momentum, and the Delete button is tapped while the table is still decelerating. Which causes a crash :(

From what I can understand, it's because I've just deleted the entities, but because the tableview is still scrolling (while the dismiss animation is completing) the tableView tries to dequeue cells that's about to appear (because of the scrolling) but then crashes because there are no entities anymore.

- If viewDidAppear was called as when a model view is dismissed I could update Home there (but it isn't called).
- If the unwind segue had a closure that was called when the animation completed I could update Home there (but it doesn't as far as I can find).

So for now I'm manually calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and using the closure there to refresh the Home controller...

```
if let nc = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController, home = nc.topViewController as? HomeViewController {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { _ in
        self.model.deleteEntities()
        home.refresh()

    })
}
```

Which works, but feels wrong (I guess because I feel like it's 'bad' for the Detail controller to have to know about the Home controller). Any advice on what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the presented view controller's `viewWillDisappear:`, or in the presenting view controller's `viewWillAppear:`, grab `self.transitionCoordinator` and call `notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:` - the block will be called just when the completion block from `dismissViewController` would be, when the animation is over.

Comment: "If viewDidAppear was called as when a modal view is dismissed" It _is_ called, so I don't quite understand that conditional...

Comment: Thanks! `notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:` is just what I wanted! I'm setting it in prepare for segue and using the unwind. I was also surprised that `viewWillAppear:` isn't called, but I _think_ it's because I'm using a custom presentation controller that doesn't take up the full screen.

Comment: "but I think it's because I'm using a custom presentation controller that doesn't take up the full screen" That's exactly why - thanks for adding that detail.